# What is the technique of obtaining the value number k from a sequence of numbers?

Tags: c++, sequence

Given the sequence s: 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, ...
For a natural number k, 0< k <=1000, determine the value of the element on k position from s sequence.
Example: for k=2, the value is 1 and for k=8, the value is 2

Here is the code:

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<math.h>
ofstream f("sir.out");

float Equation (int a, int b, int c)
{ int d;
  float x1,x2;
  d=b*b-4*a*c;
  if(d<0) return -32000;
  else if(d==0) { x1=-b/(2*a);
              if(x1>0) return x1;
              else return -32000;
            }
   else { x1=(-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a);
          x2=(-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
          if(x1>x2) if(x1>0) return x1;
                    else return -32000;
          else if(x2>0) return x2;
               else return -32000;
        }
}

void main()
{ int k,n;
  float x;
  cin>>k;
  x=Equation(1,1,-2*k);
  n=x*(x+1)/2;
  if(n==x) f<<n;
  else f<<k-n*(n+1)/2;
  f.close();
}
```

Could you, please, explain me a little bit how this works? I understand the function, but I'm not sure about how the value is obtained...

Comment: Which part are you stuck with?  Have you tried running this in the debugger to follow its behaviour?

Comment: That sequence isn't 1000 elements long, or you missed a `6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying:

Let  `x(x+1)/2 = k`
`Equation` solves for `x` using the quadratic formula.
Then `n=x*(x+1)/2`  which should make `n==k` unless something weird happened.
Then if `n==x` `n` is your answer
Otherwise output `k - n*(n+1)/2`

---

What I would do is:

Find out how many full sequences you've passed. Then just count out the difference.
To do so you would solve for `x` in `x(x+1)/2 = k`  Then round `x` down.
Then you do `k - |x|(|x| + 1)/2` (here the `|` are for rounding down)

---

So can you spot where your solution deviated from mine?

---

Actually, mine neglects to account for the case when `x == |x|`
Your code was almost correct, just change it to:

```
void main()
{ 
  int k;
  cin>>k;
  int n = Equation(1,1,-2*k);
  int x = n*(n+1)/2;
  if (x == k) f<<n;
  else f<<k - x;
  f.close();
}
```

Comment: Your method is more appealing to me. That n was hindering me from understanding the code, but now it's obvious that is easier to get to the solution by rounding x down. Thank you, a lot!

Comment: @user1012732 I've included the fix to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider producing all of the terms in the sequence in order, storing them in a data structure with indexing (such as a vector), and then simply looking up the appropriate k (bearing in mind that your vector will index from zero, while your assignment apparently does not).

Comment: not responsive to question

Comment: This is by far the easiest method to find the k, but I forgot to mention that I need to use the quadratic equation in order to solve the problem. Thank you for idea, anyway!